# How do i add soapHeader to service built in asp.net core

Tags: authentication, soap, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I built a service in asp.net core which is accessible via wsdl below. I want to add authheader to this wsdl. How do i achieve this? I am able to test this service using Postman with success. I used below code to make it look like a soap service.

```
app.UseSoapEndpoint<SampleService>("/webservice/SS.asmx", new BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
```

`<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" name="SampleService">
    <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
    <xs:element name="Test">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="TestResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TestResult" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="SampleService_Test_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Test"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="SampleService_Test_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:TestResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="SampleService">
    <wsdl:operation name="Test">
    <wsdl:input message="tns:SampleService_Test_InputMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output message="tns:SampleService_Test_OutputMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_SampleService" type="tns:SampleService">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="Test">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/SampleService/Test" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="SampleService">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_SampleService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_SampleService">
    <soap:address location="http://localhost:32156/webservice/SS.asmx"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>`